# Graceful reboot on CentOS from command line (worried about database corruption)

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, restart, reboot

I have always been a WHM/Cpanel guy so whenever the need to gracefully reboot the server came around I just used the gui command in WHM to do so.

Now, I have a situation where I do not have WHM/Cpanel and need to do the same from command line after ssh'ing in.  This is a vm inside a vpc (VMware) that is dedicated to MySQL/MariaDB only running centos.  The kernel was recently updated through yum and the reboot is needed to take affect.

I have found quite a lot of differing opinions on this when searching such as just doing something as simple as :

```
# reboot
or
# shutdown -r
```

**My main concerns are :**

1. Using the correct command for my situation
2. This vm is strictly for our databases which use innodb, but of course MySQL itself uses myisam.  The last thing I want to do is end up with corrupted data upon reboot and our db's don't function.  Does the `reboot` take care of this or should I be doing a `service mysql stop` before the reboot?  Along with that, will it restart automatically after reboot or is `service mysql start` going to be needed?

Comment: You are better off using "init" and a runlevel.  No matter what you use, you need to have a graceful shutdown in your init.d scripts to shut MySQL down.  MySQL can use either MyISAM or InnoDB for its internal tables.

Comment: Yeah, exactly... the database stuff is what I am concerned about.  Can you elaborate on your comments... init, runlevel, init.d scripts, etc?  I'm not familiar with any of that other than knowing the scripts exist.

Comment: Add repair MyISAM on restart option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands will call the required run-levels at shutdown and or reboot either way.

`shutdown -r` and `reboot` are the same thing provided you just call them 'as is' with no additional options.

```
shutdown -r now = reboot after shutdown.
reboot = shutdown then reboot
```

Extract from the usage help;

```
[root@test ~]# reboot --help
usage: reboot [-n] [-w] [-d] [-f] [-h] [-i]
        -n: don't sync before halting the system
        -f: force halt/reboot, don't call shutdown.
```

Note that if you call `shutdown -f` it will force halt/reboot, and not call shutdown, likewise -n is not what you want. Doing this is bad as it won't stop services gracefully via there init scripts and you might end up with data loss and or corruption in your case.

```
[root@test~]# shutdown --help
Usage:    shutdown [-akrhHPfnc] [-t secs] time [warning message]
          -r:      reboot after shutdown.
```

You may have noticed when CentOS starts it runs through a list of services and attempts to start them. At shutdown and reboots (normally) the same list is called to `stop` the services gracefully.

If you are really very paranoid about your databases and want to be doubly sure they are stopped before you reboot then you can issue the `stop` command directly.

```
`/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
`/etc/init.d/mariadb stop`
```

You will then get a confirmation that the services are stopped. Then you can issue your `reboot` or `shutdown -r now` command.

On start up it should restart any services (like your Db's) provided they where installed correctly. You can check this by running the following command `chkconfig --list` then look down the list for the things your interested in and you should expect to see them 'start' at run-level 3 and 'stop' at run-level 6.

e.g

```
chkconfig --list
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and information here - this is exactly what I was looking for and confirms pretty much what I wanted to do.  For the record, just because I am paranoid I will probably issue the MySQL stop prior to the reboot :).  Thanks!

Comment: No worries :)and yes there is no harm at all stopping the db's - I do it on some of my bigger ones - but not smaller or dev stuff. And hopefully you take backup etc in case anything else happens to the DB anyway!

Comment: Worked like a charm, but I just want to point out you need a time value given like `shutdown -r now` or else it will tell you a time is required.  Thanks again.